# image cannot get from database during display in the page by using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, html, image, codeigniter

I am trying to display an image and data from database to the page. Here is my code,problem is will not get any image but i get the data from the database. Please help.
**Controller Page**

```
public function gallery5()
{  
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->library('upload');
$this->load->model('Login_set');
$page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);   
$data['e']=$this->Login_set->select1(); 
$this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_galery_event.php',$data);
}
public function gallery5_insert()
{
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('Login_set');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('id','id');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('events','events','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description','description','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('images','images','required');
$config['upload_path']          = 'application/views/App_stay/photo1/';
$config['max_size']             = '100';
$config['max_width']            = '1024';
$config['max_height']           = '768';
$this->load->library('upload', $config); 
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('images'))
{
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);
$data['e']=$this->Login_set->select1_edit();
$this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_galery_event.php', $data);
}
else
{
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$this->Login_set->add_events();
$page_id =$this->uri->segment(3);
$data['e']=$this->Login_set->select1_edit();
$this->load->view('App_stay/pages/hotel1_galery_event.php', $data);
}
}
```

**View Page**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Welcome/gallery5_insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
foreach ($e->result_array() as $value){        
?>
<div class="form-group has-info ">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $value['event_id'];?>">
<?php }?>              
<div class="form-group has-info col-lg-7">
<label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Event title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="events" id="events" >
</div>                                   
<div class="form-group has-info col-lg-7 ">
<label>Event Description</label>
<textarea id="description" name="description" class="form-control " rows="3"></textarea><br><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-info col-lg-7">
<label>Event Related images</label>
<input type="file" name="images"><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-info col-lg-7">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<span>SUBMIT</span>
</button>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>   
</div>  
</header>
<div> 
<h2 class="text-center"> OUR NEW EVENTS.......</h2>
</div>
<div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover text-center">
<tr class="bg-default">
<th>EVENT TITLE</th> 
<th>EVENT DESCRIPTION</th> 
<th>EVENT RELATED IMAGES</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($e ->result_array() as $val)
{ 
?>
<tr class="bg-default">
<td>
<?php  
echo "<br>";                                            
echo $val['event_title'];
?>
</td>
<td>
<?php  
echo "<br>";                 
echo $val['event_description'];                            
?>
</td>
<td>
<img  src="<?php echo base_url('Application/views/App_stay/'.$val['image_path']) ;?>" width="102"  height="91">
</td>
<td>   
<a href="<?php echo site_url("Welcome/gallery5");?>" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<span> DELETE</span>
</button>
</a>&nbsp
<a href="<?php echo site_url("Welcome/gallery6");?>" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<span> EDIT</span>
</button>
</a><br>
</td>
<?php
}
?>
</tr> 
</table>
```

**Model Page**

```
public function add_events()
{ 
$this->form_validation->set_message('events','events','required');
$this->form_validation->set_message('description','description','required');
$this->form_validation->set_message('images','images','required');
$this->load->database();
$this->load->helper('url');
$data=array
(
'event_id'=>'',
'hotel_id'=>1,
'event_title'=>$this->input->post('events'),
'event_description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
'image_path'=>$this->upload->data()
);
$this->db->insert('event_hotel1',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not store images inside the application folder

change the path  and create a folder outside the application folder:

```
  $config['upload_path']  = 'uploads';
```

also change in the view:

```
   <?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$val['image_path'] ;?>
```